# Is it possible to vectorize this python function to run on gpu?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, gpu, vectorization, numba

I have this function (see below) which takes a tuple of point coordinates and returns a bool if the point is within a shapely polygon (global variable). I want to vectorize it to take an array of tuples and return the equivalent array of bool.

It works nicely with numpy.vectorize, but it's slow (6-7s), especially since i'm calling it within a for loop.

I read that running functions on GPU might be faster than running it on a single core. This is what I tried based on examples on the internet, but I get `TypeError: invalid signature: 'str' instance not allowed` on the function decorator.

What's wrong with the function signature and how do I fix it?

```
import shapely.geometry as sp
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

#the matrix of tuples:
obj_location = np.empty((800,800), object)
for idx in np.ndindex(maxY,maxX):
    obj_location[idx] = idx

#the polygon
poly=sp.Polygon([(200,200),(200,600),(600,600),(600,200)])

#function definition
@nb.vectorize(['bool(tuple)'], target='cuda')
def inside(point_coordinates):
    (y,x) = point_coordinates
    return poly.contains(sp.Point(x,y))

#call function
inside(obj_location)
```

Comment: Shapely is already highly optimized to begin with and also has built in support for vectorization. [see here](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#performance). If you still wanted to use numba.vectorize, you would need to to manually code `poly.contains(sp.Point(x,y))` as numba doesn't know what a sp.Polygon object is. The function you vectorize can't have types not understood by Numba. To see what I mean, replace `'bool(tuple)'` with `'void(int32[:, :, :])'` and it will throw a `TypingError`

Comment: [Here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/jit-compilation.html#vectorized-functions-ufuncs-and-dufuncs) is the documentation for `@numba.vectorize()` functions

Comment: You might want post your original solution that runs in 6-7s and see if the community can help you optimize that instead. After looking at some of your other posts I can tell that your concerned about performance and your hoping vectorization or GPU's are your answer.  I once thought similarly myself, but shortly discovered that numpy, pandas, shapely(and a few other data science libs) are all highly optimized and when used correctly are plenty fast 98% of the time. Using these libs plus python multiprocessing module should cover it for most cases.

Comment: When that doesn't cover it you can look into numpy and pandas optimizations and find they can be configured/compiled for multi-core setups or increased performance. Additionally there is [cython](http://cython.org/) which can be used in conjunction with numpy, pandas, scipy and other scientific libs to achieve even faster results.

Comment: @bigjake While it is true the libraries are highly optimized, that does not mean the number of cores is equivalent. A CPU will have a maximum of 16 whilst a GPU could run several thousands operations at a time, probably making it faster for point intersection calculations. It's kind of why video games run on GPU despite CPUs being plenty fast.